# Django Admin Panel not working

Tags: django, django-urls, administration

I am using Django 1.7 on OSX Yosemite.

For some reason, when I go to my default project URL `/admin`, the administration panel isn't coming up. Instead, I get a `404` as shown below.

[image]

I have  `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))` in my `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`, so why isn't this working?

Completely lost here.

Comment: Missing `$`, `r'^admin/$'`?

Comment: Can you post the full urls.py file?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a '/' after admin. The regex in your urls.py checks for a '/' after admin. Eg:'https://yourdomainname/admin/'